# replacing column names in a query with values in a lookup

Tags: sql, join, view

I am working in a SQL Express database with a couple of tables similar the following...

`Table 1` contains a series of data whose column names reflect the type of control on a user input form - something like the following...

```
ID, Text1, Text2, Combo1, Combo2, Num1, Num2  
1, "DP01", "WASW", "John Smith", "123 Maple St", 12, 576  
2, "DP02", "WABW", "Jane Smith", "234 River Dr", 23, 34  
3, "DP03", "WADM", "James Smith", "567 Dump Rd", 3, 986  
4, "DP04", "WARV", "Joe Smith", "678 Main St", 59, 124
```

`Table 2` contains some metadata including the title of the fields referenced in Table 1.  Something like...

```
ID, FieldName, Title  
1, Text1, PermitNumber  
2, Text2, FCode  
3, Combo1, OwnerName  
4, Combo2, Address  
5, Num1, OwnerID  
6, Num2, AddressID
```

I did not design or create the database, but it is what I have to work with.

What I'd like to be able to do is query data from Table 1 using the Title values from Table 2.  I expect this could be done by using join(s) and creating a view, but am not sure what the syntax would be for doing this.  Ultimately what I'd like the view to show is...

```
ID, PermitNumber, FCode, OwnerName, Address, OwnerID, AddressID  
1, "DP01", "WASW", "John Smith", "123 Maple St", 12, 576  
2, "DP02", "WABW", "Jane Smith", "234 River Dr", 23, 34  
3, "DP03", "WADM", "James Smith", "567 Dump Rd", 3, 986  
4, "DP04", "WARV", "Joe Smith", "678 Main St", 59, 124
```

Is this possible?

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a cursor or a while to build dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @fieldName varchar(32), @title varchar(32)
DECLARE @sql_cmd varchar(512)
SET @sql_cmd='SELECT '

DECLARE sql_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT FieldName, Title FROM table_2 ORDER BY ID

OPEN sql_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM sql_cursor INTO @fieldName, @Title

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql_cmd = @sql_cmd + @fieldName + ' AS ' + @Title + ', '

    FETCH NEXT FROM sql_cursor
    INTO @fieldName, @Title
END;

CLOSE sql_cursor
DEALLOCATE sql_cursor

SET @sql_cmd = SUBSTRING(@sql_cmd,0,LEN(@sql_cmd)-2) + ' FROM table_1'
EXEC(@sql_cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply an [`UNPIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to `Table 1`.  This will give you:

```
1, Text1, "DP01"
1, Text2, "WASW"
1, Combo1, "John Smith"
1, Combo2, "123 Maple St"
...
4, Num1, 59
4, Num2, 124
```

Join this to `Table 2` to get

```
1, Text1, "DP01", PermitNumber  
1, Text2, "WASW", FCode
1, Combo1, "John Smith", OwnerName
1, Combo2, "123 Maple St", Address
...
4, Num1, 59, OwnerID
4, Num2, 124, AddressID
```

Finally `PIVOT` that omitting the colum names from Table1 and you will have your desired format.